# CSS file not applied in different versions?

Tags: css

I have a problem with CSS file, if I browse my application via another machine or through published folder , the CSS file is not getting applied but the same CSS file works fine in machine where the application is set up. The CSS file is not compatible with IE6,IE7, IE9 and firefox. Please let me know how to make it compatiable in all versions.

Comment: you need to show some code - otherwise how can one help??

Answer (score 0):

use relative paths for the css files